# How do I store symbol names from the stack trace in GDB Script variables?

Tags: c, gdb

Supposed this is my stack trace:

```
#0 f1 () at foo.c:n
#1 f2 () at foo.c:n
#2 f3 () at foo.c:n
#3 f4 () at foo.c:n
```

I want to be able to do something like this in a GDB script:

```
printf "function %s called function %s\n", $f1_name, $f2_name
```

Is this possible? Is there a struct somewhere with this kind of metadata?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get this is to use the Python API.

There is a more horrible way, too: use "set logging" to redirect to a file.  Then, "bt" or whatever else you like.  Then, undo the logging.  Use the "shell" command to rewrite the file to a gdb script that sets convenience variables.  Finally, "source" the script.

I suggest sticking to the Python approach though.  You can write a convenience function in Python to expose this quite easily.